# Clliptic lowpass filter IC

Tags: low-pass

While checking old audio equipment, I stumbled upon the RF5609A filter IC.
The only resources I found about this IC are:

[image: datasheet pag.1]

[image: datasheet pag.2]

[image: datasheet pag.3]

Looks like a 7-poles/6-zeros Elliptic LPF, used before and after AD/DA conversion.

I didn't know those ICs to I'm just trying to understand how they work, specifically how the clock input should to be used.

**Pag.2** says that the sampling rate of the IC is 50 times the clock frequency.
**Pag.3** says that clock to corner freq.ratio is 100 (I guess because the corner frequency is half the sample rate clock).
Does that mean, for example, that if the AD/DA system is sampling at 100 KHz, you'd need the filter corner frequency at 50 KHz, so the clock input should be 50*100 = 5 Mhz?

Also, what is the order of this filter, given the spec 7-poles/6-zeros?

Comment: Well max clock frequency is 2.5MHz, so if you need a corner frequency of 50 kHz, you're pushing this chip beyond its capabilities (since a 5MHz clock would be needed).

Comment: thanks, I don't mean to use this chip, I don't have any requirement, I'm just trying to understand how this work

Comment: @DimitriPetrucci how familiar are you with the concept of digital signal processing, especially with filtering in digital domain?

Comment: EG&G used charge-coupled-arrays. thus the area of onchip capacitances allowed precise ratios **ratios** of poles and of zeros, with the absolute frequency set as ratio of the CLOCK.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact technology used in this IC, but it is clear that it is doing discrete-time analog processing.

As such there is no discretization of the signal level, just of the time samples. All of z-transform and discrete time methodologies apply, but considerations for the finite bandwidth and slew rate of analog components have to enter consideration. Thus the 50xNyquist requirement.

Modern ICs that do the same type of processing are known as [switched-capacitor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_capacitor) ICs, it is possible that this one is an early adopter of that technology.

Similar constraints also apply to [chopper amplifiers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopper_(electronics)). Although in their case they are better examples of modulators, of which time discretization is a special case.

Comment: Yes - it is a switched-capacitor technique.